# How do I use condition with rows in a dataframe (weighted average, R language)?

Tags: r, dataframe, weighted-average

I  need to calculate the weighted average of each row in the dataframe, where:
Does anyone know how to do it using the R language?
regards

```
t1 <- c(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9)
t2 <- c(6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 7)
df <- data.frame(t1 = t1, t2=t2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

if value <= 5 , weight is 1
if value > 5 and <= 8 , weight is 2
if value > 8 , weight is 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `tidyverse` to calculate the weighted mean for each row.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  # Add row numbers
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  # Convert to long format
  gather(Group, Value, -rowid) %>%
  # Assign weight
  mutate(Weight = case_when(
    Value <= 5                   ~1,
    Value >  5 & Value <= 8      ~2,
    Value > 8                    ~3,
    TRUE                         ~NA_real_
  )) %>%
  # Calculated weighted average
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  summarize(Weighted_Mean = weighted.mean(Value, Weight)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
#   rowid Weighted_Mean
#   <int>         <dbl>
# 1     1          4.33
# 2     2          4.67
# 3     3          4.5 
# 4     4          5   
# 5     5          5.67
# 6     6          8.2
```

Comment: The OP wants means *by row*, not by column.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks. I have updated my answer. But why do we have different results? Perhaps I misunderstand the meaning of weighted average?

Comment: `weighted.mean` normalizes the weights to sum to `1`. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution, function `findInterval` does the main part. Then multiply the result with `df` and get the row means.

```
t1 <- c(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9)
t2 <- c(6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 7)
df <- data.frame(t1 = t1, t2=t2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cp <- c(-Inf, 5, 8, Inf)
```

**Edit.**

If the weights are normalized to sum to `1`, then the right answer will be any of the following two.

```
wt <- sapply(df, findInterval, cp)
rowSums(df*(wt/apply(wt, 1, sum)))
#[1] 4.333333 4.666667 4.666667 5.000000 5.666667 8.200000

sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i)
  weighted.mean(df[i,], sapply(df, findInterval, cp)[i,]))
#[1] 4.333333 4.666667 4.666667 5.000000 5.666667 8.200000
```

These results are now equal to the results in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to multiply by weights & then divide by their sum (equal to `weighted.mean` function in R):

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(t1, t2),
            list(weights = ~ case_when(. <= 5 ~ 1,
                                       . > 5 & . <= 8 ~ 2,
                                       TRUE ~ 3))) %>%
  mutate(rowMeanWeighted = rowSums(.[, 1:2] * .[, 3:4]) / rowSums(.[, 3:4])) %>%
  select(-contains("weights"))
```

Output:

```
  t1 t2 rowMeanWeighted
1  1  6        4.333333
2  2  6        4.666667
3  4  5        4.500000
4  6  3        5.000000
5  7  3        5.666667
6  9  7        8.200000
```

Comment: Different than my results but the same as Rui Barradas. What is the definition of a weighted average?

Comment: @www, I take it as multiplication by a weight given the description above. Not sure if the right approach though, let's see what the OP says.

Comment: I did not see multiplication by a weight mentioned in the original post, but let’s wait for clarification.

Comment: @www, tbh after another thought even if it would be explicitly mentioned a result that doesn't go between minimum and maximum of the vector wouldn't make much sense, have deleted my first answer